# use glm method if loess method returning error

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
df

Date      Ovserv  Team
1/1/2012  10      USA
1/2/2012  30      USA
1/3/2012  28      USA
1/4/2012  79      USA
1/5/2012  24      USA
1/1/2012  45      Japan
1/2/2012  10      Japan
1/3/2012  56      Japan
1/4/2012  60      Japan
1/5/2012  67      Japan
```

I really like loess and like to use it whenever I can. I am working with variety of different data frames where I am trying to use loess method to graph. However, due to some inconsistencies (some data frames not having enough data points), I am getting this error:

```
Error in predLoess(object$y, object$x, newx, object$s, object$weights,
```

Would it be possible to use `method="glm"` in the event that I would get error using `ggplot2` method "loess"?

```
ggplot(df, (Date, Observ, group=Team, colour=Team)) + 
   geom_smooth(method="loess", se=T, size=1)
```

Any ideas how I would address this problem?

Comment: Check whether the data frame has sufficient size, and then only add the `geom_smooth` layer if the size is big enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The statement `class(try(loess(y~x, df)))=="try-error"` will give `TRUE` if there's not sufficient data for loess.

You can try something along the lines of

```
ggplot(....) + geom_smooth(method=ifelse(class(try(loess(y~x, df)))=="try-error",
                                          "glm","loess")....)
```

And add `silent=TRUE` to the `try` arguments if you don't want to see the error messages.